# vaadin: where can i set Reindeer.TABSHEET_SMALL on tabsheet

Tags: themes, vaadin

I am using the default Reindeer them and would like to change the tabsheet size to  Reindeer.TABSHEET_SMALL

Where can I set the option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding a style name for the tabsheet:

```
tabsheet.addStyleName(Reindeer.TABSHEET_SMALL);
```